# Angular 2 webpack import issue

Tags: angular, typescript

Some time ago I wrote a simple dashboard with the ng2-admin template using Angular2 typescript. (On a mac machine)
Because an URL changed I needed to change this in the application and recompile it, but now there is a weird dependency error I cant get rid of (Now using a windows pc).

```
ERROR in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\Moritz\Desktop\alfred-admin-
panel\node_modules\amcharts3\amcharts\amcharts.js'

ERROR in ./src/app/theme/components/baAmChart/baAmChart.scss
Module build failed:
@import "~ammap3/ammap/ammap";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: 
C:\Users\Moritz\Desktop\alfred-admin-panel\node_modules\ammap3\ammap\ammap.
```

The import statement looks like this.

```
import 'amcharts3';
import 'amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/responsive/responsive.js';
import 'amcharts3/amcharts/serial.js';

import 'ammap3';
import 'ammap3/ammap/maps/js/worldLow';
```

I tried to install amcharts3 with the following command

```
npm install amcharts3 --save
```

Which installs the library (node_modules), and one of these errors go away. When I now install the second library

```
npm install ammap3 --save
```

It deletes the library (from node_modules) from before and installs ammap3.

So basically I can only install 1 library at the same time because the other one gets deleted.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Something strange: did you not missed the extension of your file when you import this file?

`@import "~ammap3/ammap/ammap";` in your `baAmChart.scss`

Because webpack tell you it cannot find the file `C:\Users\Moritz\Desktop\alfred-admin-panel\node_modules\ammap3\ammap\ammap.`

Can you post your `baAmChart.scss` file please?